# Spirit of murdered waitress seeks revenge

Tags: horror, identify-this-movie

This horror movie was probably released around the same time as [Titanic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titanic_(1997_film)), but not very sure.

A young waitress was serving in a bar/night club and some drunk men put her on the table and asked her to dance. Then someone pulled her skirt off. Later she was being chased and then she  was murdered. After the waitress is murdered, her spirit comes back and lures other men into sex and then kills them.

At the end, many houses get on fire and some people are leaving/fleeing that area.

Which movie is this?

Comment: Can you add more detail? Like maybe what kind of settings, environments, describe accents, locations, era in which the film took place?

Comment: @DustinDavis: I added some more details.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Could it be [Hellgate](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0097498/) from 1990?

From the IMDb synopsis:

*A motorcycle gang kidnaps a young woman, Josie, from a diner and brutally kills her. Many years later, the girl's father finds a magic crystal that can bring the life back to dead objects. He uses it to re-animate his daughter. He lets her seduce any young man that comes to visit the small town and then kills them.*

[image]

That's my best guess.

Comment: I believe this is it. Thanks for the answer. Too bad I cannot find it anywhere to watch it. If you know any resource, please point it out.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds somewhat like *Jennifer's Body* ([IMDB link](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1131734/)), notable as the first screenplay by Diablo Cody (*Juno*).  However, *Jennifer's Body* was released in 2009.

Comment: Jennifer's Body is not that movie. The first line of my question mentioned that it was released in or before 1997. I am not a fan of downvoting, hence only pointing it out that others aren't very forgiving. Thanks for your reply though.